# Java clear textfield after "Enter"

Tags: java, swing, textfield

How can I clear the text in the input field after the user submits the message.

Im working on something similar to a chat. I've gotten to the point where when the user submits the message it gets sent but the message typed remains in the textbox, how can i make it automatically clear.

This is a part of my code, not sure if its enough.

```
private JTextField in;

public AESGUI() {

JLabel info = new JLabel("Message");
in = new JTextField(40);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the JTextField API as well as its parent class, JTextComponent, where you'll find the method you need: setText(""). Just call it in the code that responds to "Enter", possibly an ActionListener that has been added to the JTextField.

If this information doesn't help you, then you'll have to give us more information. Note that your current posted code tells us very little about your problem and does not help us figure out where your problem is.

Comment: Yah, i figured the code was nothing, there is no "problem" its just not as effective as I wanted, ill take a look at the things you sent me, thank :)

Comment: @Cody: If your still stuck, please update your question and send me a comment to let me know about the update. With more code and information, we'll likely be able to get you on your way.

Comment: setText worked perfectly. Can't believe it was that easy. I just wrote 'in.setText(""); ' in the actionlistener (after the message is sent) and it fixed everything. Thank you very much :D

Comment: @Cody: regarding your deleted question -- your reply was totally uncalled for. You are free to leave this forum.